# Pass value from state of stateful class to different widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a function:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
```

Inside *class _LoginPageState extends State* I have a bool variable 'registered' that changes within setState to true when user registers for the first time. How can I pass this value to my main function whenever it gets changed? Additionally, this variable needs to be changed from different place as well to true. Based on it I wanna show different screen to my user - something like below:

```
home: Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: Container(
      child: registered ? OnboardingPage() : HomePage(),
    ),
  ),
```

Could you show me some code or guide me? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your Login page

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool registered;
  
  // ...

  void gotoSecondPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(registered),));
  }
}
```

Your other page

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  bool registered;

  SecondPage(this.registered);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        child: widget.registered ? OnboardingPage() : HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this variable is changed inside `_LoginPageState` you can redirect the user according to its value as below:

```
// BEGIN: TODO
// registered = true;
// END: TODO
Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => registered ? OnboardingPage() : HomePage()),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `StreamBuilder` and `Provider` to first get the data asynchronously, and then send that data to different places in your widget tree. Something like:

```dart
final StreamController _controller = StreamController();

// Provide this _controller in your top level widget tree
return Provider<StreamController>(
    create: (context) => _controller,
    child: MaterialApp(...),
);
```

In your `_LoginPageState`, whenever you get a new `registered` value:

```dart
// ... other lines
var registered = async getUserRegisterStatus() // sample method

// Add the new value to Stream
Provider.of<StreamController>.add(registered);
```

You can then use this controller to notify any below widget of the change of value:

```dart
// Sample place that needs the value
home: Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: StreamBuilder<bool>(
       initialValue: false
       stream: Provider.of<StreamController>.stream,
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
         var registered = snapshot.data;
         return Container(
            child: registered ? OnboardingPage() : HomePage(),
         );
       }
    ),
  ),
```